# HTML iframe not working when i write src= of facebook

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I have this code that is working ok:

```
<div class="facebook">
          <div id="likebox-frame">
          <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbigfishbudapest&amp;width=320&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color=&amp;stream=true&amp;header=false&amp;height=395" 
          scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
         </div>
        </div>
```

I need that instead of taking me to this facebook fan page:
https://www.facebook.com/bigfishbudapest/

It needs to take me to this facebook fan page: 
https://www.facebook.com/bigfishlaspalmas/

Comment: you get to the page you specify in the plugin, why would anyone want to go to a different page than the one you like(d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the page reference in the source (src) attribute will display the page you specified.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbigfishlaspalmas&amp;width=320&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color=&amp;stream=true&amp;header=false&amp;height=395" 
      scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**src**="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F**bigfishbudapest**&width=320&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&border_color=&stream=true&header=false&height=395"

**src**="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F**bigfishlaspalmas**&width=320&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&border_color=&stream=true&header=false&height=395"

Answer (score 1):

> Facebook is using a X-Frame-Options in the HTTP response header so you can't load in a iFrame.

[you can go through this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)